# Is there a way to list all the subpages and asp/jsp/php of a website?

Tags: php, asp-classic

I was wondering if there's a way to display a list that includes all the *subpages* and all the *.asp/.php/.jsp* links of a website? Like a tree diagram or something like that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like presentation you can find below?

```
<pre>bootstrap/
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
└── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
</pre>
```

Source: 
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Nah, I mean like to show this type of tree diagram for ANY websites, but still, thanks a lot!